# How to route vpn traffic so it can only use ssh

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, routing

### I want to make an SSH connection

e.g `ssh pi@123.123.123.123 -p 22`

SSH connection can only be made when connected to VPN tunnel.
I can connect to VPN tunnel like this

```
echo PASS | sudo openconnect --juniper https:/example/ -u user --passwd-on-stdin
```

Now the SSH connection works!

### **BUT**

When I'm connected to the tunnel it changes my public IP 176.234.123.12 to 10.13.25.1. Because of that my web server dosen't work. Because it routes all the traffic trough tunnel.

**I want to send SSH command through VPN connection, but I don't want my VPN  to route all the traffic.**

How can I do this?

### What I tried so far

I tried to make an bash script that connects to the network and then sends ssh command and after that disconnects, but thats really bad solution.

Also tried openSSH ProxyCommand, but I think misunderstood that

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="echo PASS | sudo openconnect --juniper https://example/ -u user --passwd-on-stdin" user@host
```

I saw post about openVPN using `route-nopull`

But I'm not sure how to redirect traffic with OpenConnect